# When I try to write a variable including different sets I get an error. How can I solve Gams Error 198?

Tags: gams-math

I get an error when I try to use a variable as v(i+1 , j+1).
How can I write v(i+1 , j+1) in GAMS code if I defined only v(i , j) as a variable before?

Related parts in the code are as following:

```
variable v(t,f);

eqn3(f,p,t) ..   v(t,f)=g= r(t,p)+ (0.2*0.4*H(p)*v(t+1,f+1) + v(t+1,f)*((1-(0.4)*H(p))*(1-0.8)+(0.4)*H(p)*0.8)+ v(t+1,f-1)*((1-(0.4)*H(p))*0.8);
```

I get Error 198 in following parts in eqn3 : `v(t+1 , f+1)`  , `v(t+1, f )` and  `v(t+1 , f-1)`.

Comment: FYI: I added a link to my reply, that should help with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you get error 198, you should actually see a little more than the number. Something like this:

```
  198 Set used in 'ord' or lag is not ordered.
         Hint: Some of the elements of the set were used before this
         was initialized and the order was different from the order used
         in this set. Try to initialize the set earlier.
```

Did you try to follow that hint?

In general, you should try to share a reproducible minimal example here when asking questions like this. That would help a lot to offer you some help here.

Edit: From the code block you added now, one can see, that the set `t` seems to be the problem. Though, you don't show how this got generated. Here is some explanation why this error is triggered in general and what one can do, to avoid it:

https://www.gams.com/35/docs/UG_FixingErrors.html#UG_FixingErrors_ErrorO